# Check Camel config at load-time?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-boot

We're using Spring Boot for an application, with Camel for routing. We split most routes with an endpoint "URI" String, mainly for testability's sake:

```
rest("/foo").post().to("direct:foo");
from("direct:foo").process(exchange -> {
    exchange.getIn().setBody(service.doStuff());
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
});
```

However if we mis-type one of the `"direct:foo"` strings, we don't get an error until the route is invoked. I'd like to be able to get the error earlier, as part of the application's startup process.

Obviously using static finals instead of String literals will keep us from mis-typing an individual endpoint value, but it won't help with the situation where one endpoint doesn't go anywhere, or we're using one for a `from` without sending anything to it.

Is there a way I can ask Camel to verify all routes have working to/from endpoints, once Spring has finished scanning the classpath and building beans?

Comment: But how can camel know where should a "from" go?